# CakePHP AppController.php issues

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having an issue with a cakephp script. It was written with cakephp version 2.5.1.

I'm getting fatal error: Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in /lib/Cake/Controller/CakeErrorController.php on line 46.

The original AppController.php file looked like this:

```
<?php

if (session_id() == '') {
session_start();
}
class AppController
{
public $components = array('Auth');
public $helpers = array(
    0      => 'Form',
    'Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtml')
    );

public function beforeFilter()
{
    global $loguser;
    global $username;
    global $siteChanges;
    global $paypalAdaptive;
    global $user_level;
    global $setngs;
    global $price;
    global $colors;
    global $parent_categori;
    global $googlecode;
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => '/', 'action' => '/login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => '/', 'action' => '/');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
AuthComponent::ALL => array(
    'fields'    => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),
    'userModel' => 'Users.User'
    ),
0                  => 'Form'
);

    if ($this->params['controller'] == 'api') {
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

    if ($this->params['controller'] == 'fantasyhelps') {
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }

    if ($this->params['controller'] == 'paypals') {
        App::import('Vendor', 'PayPal');
    }

    $this->Auth->allow(, , 'login', 'signup', 'emailverification', 'verification', 'index', 'setpassword', 'userprofiles', 'viewshops', 'addto', 'press', 'about', 'toppeople', 'findpeople', 'storeprofiles', 'getstoreprofile', 'listings', 'show_color', 'show_price', 'showByCategory', 'getMorePosts', 'ipnprocess', 'getmorepricecolor', 'getItemByCategory', 'ajaxSearch', 'captcha', 'forgotpassword', 'showByRelation', 'getItemByRelation', 'faq', 'contact', 'item_comments', 'changePassword', 'copyrights', 'termsofsale', 'termsofservice', 'termsofmerchant', 'privacy', 'loginwith', 'loginwithtwitter', 'changecurrency', 'downimage', 'sitemaintenance', 'getviewmore', 'customviewmore', 'orderstatus', 'getsizeqty', 'searches', 'getmoregallery', 'viewitemdesc', 'followersList', 'getmoreprofile', 'getmorestorycomment', 'followingList', 'twittlogin_save', 'item_favorited', 'merupdate', 'custupdatend', 'testing', 'bookmarklet', 'getmorecomments', 'adaptiveipnprocess', 'additemusingurl', 'giftcardipnIpn', 'ggipn', 'ggcronjob', 'nearme', 'getMorenearme', 'gifts', 'story');
    $loguser = $this->Auth->user();
    $userid = $loguser[0]['User']['id'];
    $username = $loguser[0]['User']['username'];
    $first_name = $loguser[0]['User']['first_name'];
    $username_url = $loguser[0]['User']['username_url'];
    $user_level = $loguser[0]['User']['user_level'];
    $profile_image = $loguser[0]['User']['profile_image'];
    $this->set('loguser', $loguser);
    $this->set('username', $username);
    $this->set('username_url', $username_url);
    $this->set('user_level', $user_level);
    $this->set('first_name', $first_name);
    $this->set('profile_image', $profile_image);
    $this->set('currentaction', $this->params['action']);
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $user_datas = $this->User->findById($userid);

    if (!empty($loguser) && empty($user_datas)) {
        $this->Auth->logout();
    }

    $user_status_val = $this->User->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array('User.id' => $userid)
));
    $user_status = $user_status_val['User']['user_status'];

    if ($user_status == 'disable') {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account has been disabled please contact our support'), 'default', array(), 'bad');
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        $this->redirect('/login');
    }

    $this->loadModel('Sitesetting');
    $this->loadModel('Cart');
    $this->loadModel('Orders');
    $this->loadModel('Item');
    $this->loadModel('Price');
    $this->loadModel('Color');
    $this->loadModel('Category');
    $this->loadModel('Forexrate');
    $this->loadModel('Managemodule');
    $this->loadModel('Googlecode');
    $this->loadModel('Contactseller');
    $this->loadModel('Story');
    $orderdetails = $this->Orders->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('Orders.merchant_id' => $userid)
));
    $this->set('orderdetails', $orderdetails);
    $storyCount = $this->Story->find('count', array(
'conditions' => array('userid' => $userid)
));
    $this->set('storyCounts', $storyCount);
    $managemoduleModel = $this->Managemodule->find('first');
    $this->set('managemoduleModel', $managemoduleModel);
    $params = $this->params;
    $action = $params['action'];

    if ($this->params['controller'] != 'api') {
        $this->_setLanguage();
    }

    if (($action != 'sitemaintenance') && ($action != 'login') && ($this->params['controller'] != 'api')) {
        if (!$this->isauthenticated() || ($user_level != 'god')) {
            if ($managemoduleModel['Managemodule']['site_maintenance_mode'] == 'yes') {
                $this->redirect('/sitemaintenance');
            }
        }
    }

    $messageCount = $this->Contactseller->find('count', array(
'conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
        array('merchantid' => $userid, 'sellerread' => 1),
        array('buyerid' => $userid, 'buyerread' => 1)
        )
    )
));
    $_SESSION['userMessageCount'] = $messageCount;

    if (!isset($_SESSION['language_settings'])) {
        $languageJson = file_get_contents(SITE_URL . 'language_settings.json');
        $_SESSION['language_settings'] = json_decode($languageJson, true);
        $defaultLanguage = $_SESSION['language_settings']['settings']['default'];
        Configure::write('Config.language', $defaultLanguage);
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['currency_value'])) {
        $forexrateModel = $this->Forexrate->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array('status' => 'default')
));
        $_SESSION['currency_symbol'] = $forexrateModel['Forexrate']['currency_symbol'];
        $_SESSION['currency_value'] = $forexrateModel['Forexrate']['price'];
        $_SESSION['currency_code'] = $forexrateModel['Forexrate']['currency_code'];
        $_SESSION['default_currency_code'] = $forexrateModel['Forexrate']['currency_code'];
        $_SESSION['default_currency_symbol'] = $forexrateModel['Forexrate']['currency_symbol'];
    }

    $setngs = $this->Sitesetting->find('all');
    $price = ('all');
    $forexrateModel = $this->Forexrate->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('status <>' => 'disable')
));
    $colors = $this->Color->find('all');
    $UserDetailss = $this->User->findById($userid);
    $this->set('UserDetailss', $UserDetailss);
    $this->loadModel('Shop');
    $sellerDetails = $this->Shop->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('user_id' => $userid)
));
    $this->set('sellerDetails', $sellerDetails);
    $shopDetails = $this->Shop->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array('user_id' => $userid)
));
    $this->set('shop_name', $shopDetails['Shop']['shop_name']);
    $parent_categori = $this->Category->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('category_parent' => 0)
));
    $googlecode = $this->Googlecode->find('all');

    if (!empty($userid)) {
        if (!empty($carts)) {
            foreach ($carts as $crt) {
                $itmids[] = $crt['Cart']['item_id'];
            }

            $itm_datas = $this->Item->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('Item.id' => $itmids, 'Item.status' => 'publish')
));
            $total_itms = count($itm_datas);
            $this->set('total_itms', $total_itms);
        }
    }

    $this->set('price', $price);
    $this->set('colors', $colors);
    $this->set('forexrateModel', $forexrateModel);
    $this->set('parent_categori', $parent_categori);
    $this->set('googlecode', $googlecode);
    $this->set('media_url', $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_url']);
    $this->set('setngs', $setngs);
    $siteChanges = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['site_changes'];
    $siteChanges = json_decode($siteChanges, true);
    $paypalAdaptive = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['paypaladaptive'];
    $paypalAdaptive = json_decode($paypalAdaptive, true);
    $this->set('siteChanges', $siteChanges);
    $_SESSION['site_url'] = SITE_URL;
    $_SESSION['media_url'] = SITE_URL;

    if (!empty($setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_url'])) {
        $_SESSION['media_host_name'] = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_server_hostname'];
        $_SESSION['media_url'] = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_url'];
        $_SESSION['media_server_username'] = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_server_username'];
        $_SESSION['media_server_password'] = $setngs[0]['Sitesetting']['media_server_password'];
    }

    $params = $this->params;
    $action = $params['action'];
    $this->set('action', $action);

    if ($this->params['controller'] != 'api') {
        $this->_setLanguage();
    }
}

public function isauthenticated()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    if (!empty($user)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function isauthorized()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    if (($user[0]['User']['user_level'] == 'god') || ($user[0]['User']['user_level'] == 'moderator')) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function isauthorizedpersn()
{
    $user = ();
    if (($user[0]['User']['user_level'] == 'god') || ($user[0]['User']['user_level'] == 'shop')) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function _setLanguage()
{
    if (isset($this->Cookie) && $this->Cookie->read('lang') && !$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->Cookie->read('lang'));
    }
    else if (isset($this->params['language']) && ($this->params['language'] != $this->Session->read('Config.language'))) {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->params['language']);
        $this->Cookie->write('lang', $this->params['language'], false, '20 days');
    }
}
}


$config['Settings'] = Configure::read('Settings');
define('SITE_URL', $config['Settings']['SITE_URL']);
define('SITE_NAME', $config['Settings']['SITE_TITLE']);
define('FB_ID', $config['Settings']['FB_ID']);
define('FB_SECRET', $config['Settings']['FB_SECRET']);
define('GOOGLE_ID', $config['Settings']['GOOGLE_ID']);
define('GOOGLE_SECRET', $config['Settings']['GOOGLE_SECRET']);
define('TWITTER_ID', $config['Settings']['TWITTER_ID']);
define('TWITTER_SECRET', $config['Settings']['TWITTER_SECRET']);
define('GMAIL_CLIENT_SECRET', $config['Settings'] 
['GMAIL_CLIENT_SECRET']);
define('GMAIL_CLIENT_ID', $config['Settings']['GMAIL_CLIENT_ID']);

?>
```

The first error pointed to this line: 
    $this->Auth->allow(, , 'login', 'signup', 'emailverification',
so I removed the , , and hence it became:
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'signup', 'emailverification',

The second error pointed to this line $user = (); 
So I changed it to $user = $this->Auth->user();

But this change from $user = (); to $user = $this->Auth->user(); throws a fatal error: 
Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in /lib/Cake/Controller/CakeErrorController.php on line 46

Below is the content of CakeErrorController.php. I'm told that CakeErrorController.php is a core file so I shouldn't really need to change it?

```
<?php
/**
 * Error Handling Controller
 *
 * Controller used by ErrorHandler to render error views.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. 
(http://cakefoundation.org)
*
* Licensed under The MIT License
* For full copyright and license information, please see the 
LICENSE.txt
* Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
*
* @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. 
(http://cakefoundation.org)
* @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
* @package       Cake.Controller
* @since         CakePHP(tm) v 2.0
* @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT 
License
*/

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

/**
* Error Handling Controller
*
* Controller used by ErrorHandler to render error views.
*
* @package       Cake.Controller
*/
class CakeErrorController extends AppController {

/**
* Uses Property
*
* @var array
*/
public $uses = array();

/**
* Constructor
*
* @param CakeRequest $request
* @param CakeResponse $response
*/
public function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
    $this->constructClasses();
    if (count(Router::extensions()) &&
        !$this->Components->attached('RequestHandler')
    ) {
        $this->RequestHandler = $this->Components- 
 >load('RequestHandler');
    }
    if ($this->Components->enabled('Auth')) {
        $this->Components->disable('Auth');
    }
    if ($this->Components->enabled('Security')) {
        $this->Components->disable('Security');
    }
    $this->_set(array('cacheAction' => false, 'viewPath' => 'Errors'));
}

}
```

I need help in fixing any issues you notice with the AppController.php file. I'm new at this. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, and I don't want to step on anyone's toes, but, that code looks horrible, there's so much wrong with it I don't even know where to start... `global` usage, accessing superglobals directly, manually starting a session via native calls, code outside of the class definition, public controller methods that aren't actual actions, massive amounts of unrelated code that should be in concrete controllers and/or components, etc... you really need to get that cleaned up.

That being said, your `AppController` class doesn't extend `Controller` (which it *must* do) and has no constructor itself, so there's no constructor to invoke via `parent::__construct()` in `CakeErrorController::__construct()`, hence the error.

See also **[Cookbook > Controllers](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html)**

Comment: hi @ndm, thanks for the response. i got the code from a third party who is not willing to help sort out the issues. i've been told the code is horribly written. could you kindly help me correct the two issues you noted: your AppController class doesn't extend Controller (which it must do) and has no constructor itself, so there's no constructor to invoke via parent::__construct() in CakeErrorController::__construct().  i am very new at this and don't even know where to make the corrections you mentioned. thanks for your help.

Comment: @johndoedev You just need to extend `Controller` as shown in the linked docs. For proper form you'd also need to import it. You can check the source of a fresh CakePHP setup to figure how things should look like: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.10/app/Controller/AppController.php**

Comment: thanks for that link. i have added the class AppController extends Controller and now i can see that part of the website is showing! can you tell me how to do the constructor part of your suggestion? a code sample and where to place it would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @johndoedev There's no need to add a constructor, that was just part of the explanation why the error occours, ie because there is no constructor in any of the parents.

Comment: i have accepted your answer. thanks. i just need to find an experienced cakephp programmer to sort out the other various errors and clean the codebase for me. thanks for your help today!